# Data validation range with ROW() in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Here is a link to a test spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10pofQ3TJM1FvBEPdvDq73-dm7hafhNwAbqVkfekofS8/edit#gid=0

The dropdown menus in column C are dependent on the selection in Column B.

To achieve this I have two more tabs in my sheet. The first one called "Dataset" lists the different possible options for each selection.

The "Options" tab transposes the data into rows dependent on the selected model in the production sheet's column B.

The formula for transposing the data is:
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(dataset!$A$2:$F$8,,MATCH(INDIRECT("production!$B" & ROW()),dataset!$A$1:$F$1,0)))

Back in the production tab, Column C grabs the data range in the options sheet with "data validation, dropdown (from a range)". The range in data validation should always match the current row.

So the problem: in my data validation, row 8 has the explicit range =options!A8:8, but if I move row 8 to row 1 it breaks because it is still referencing row 8. The option I had in mind was to use row() formula in my range but this isn't possible.

Is it possible to create a cell which contains the ROW() function, then reference that cell in the data validation range perhaps?

Comment: Please describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet including the relevant spreadsheet settings like the locale (country). Add some sample data bot for the source range as well for the expected result. Show what you have tried, and add the the most relevant questions that you found from this site and why they don't meet your needs.

Comment: @fred see the following posts: [1.Additional Line impacting dependent drop downs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/167880) [2.How can I make a dependent dropdown?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/166849) [3.Problem carrying data validation down through column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/164861)  Tips from links: - Use BYROW/BYCOL to generate dependent lists. - Replace your absolute refs with relative in dropdowns then inserted/copied/deleted rows will update. - etc.